# How does Rust determine the length of a slice when unsizing from an array?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

I know that a slice is like a fatptr: `(data_ptr, len)`. When I slice an array into a slice:

```rust
let arr = [0; 10];
let slice_arr = &arr[..];
```

An array doesn't have a length field like `Vec<T>`.

I know that `slice_arr.len()` can get the length of slice because `slice_arr` has a length field. How does Rust know the length field when an array is converted into a slice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array *does* have a length "parameter" of sorts. It's not a field, it's part of the type:

```rust
let x: [u8; 2] = [1, 2];
let y: [u8; 3] = x; // Error here
```

The type of `x` is `[u8; 2]`. The number of elements is *always* 2, and the type of the elements is *always* `u8`.

Because `[u8; 2]` and `[u8; 3]` are distinct types, one is *always* exactly 2 `u8`s long, and the other is *always* exactly 3 `u8`s long, the assignment from `x` into `y` fails.

When performing certain operations with arrays, the compiler has special built-in semantics for the arrays. These built-in semantics can make use of the length "parameter" (The `N` in `[T; N]`). You can manipulate and access this value at the type level using `const` generics, but that's a nightly-only feature right now.

Answer (score -4):

Use the `.len` method.

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    let arr = [0; 10];
    let slice_arr = &arr[..];
    println!("first element of the slice: {}", slice_arr[0]);
    println!("the slice has {} elements", slice_arr.len());
}
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/primitives/array.html

Comment: an array doesn't have a length parameter like Vec. 
How does Rust know the length of the array when it is converted into slices?

Comment: The question says "I know that `slice_arr.len()` can get the length of slice"